# Nested query using appsync resolver, aws dymaodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync

I need to run a query using aws appsync resolver on dynamodb based on the result of first query.
I have below user table.
[userTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVhBx.png)

First query: Find an item where userId=u1 and type=user.
Second query: Find an item where userId="RefId returned from first query" and status=complete.

I need to do this in one query in appsync resolver.

```
#set( $expValues = {} )
#set($expression="userId = :userId ")
$!{expValues.put(":userId ", { "S" : $ctx.args.input.userId })}


#if(! $util.isNullOrEmpty($ctx.args.input.type))
  #set($expression="$expression and begins_with(type)")
  $!{expValues.put(":type", { "S" : $type})}
#end

{
    "version" : "2018-05-29",
    "operation" : "Query",
    "index" : "mId_mType_index",
    "scanIndexForward" : false,
     "query" : {
        "expression":"$expression",

        #if( !${expValues.isEmpty()} )
            "expressionValues" : $utils.toJson($expValues)
        #end
    },
    #if( ${ctx.args.limit} )
        "limit": ${ctx.args.limit}
    #end
    #if( ${ctx.args.nextToken} )
        ,"nextToken": "${ctx.args.nextToken}"
    #end

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a pipeline solver in AWS AppSync. A pipeline resolver can have multiple resolver functions which can have their own data sources. The next function in a pipeline can use the result of the previous resolver.

> I need to do this in one query in appsync resolver.

I don't know why you (think) you need this, but this is not possible.